# Can we use pirated books on the Internet?

Tags: internet, piracy

Can we use pirated books available on internet, as these books are owned by someone and are someone's effort so we are accessing it without his/her permission. And these books are very expensive so we can't buy them. What is guidance of Islam on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not use pirated books unless owner (publisher/writer) has put it for free to use or you took explicit permission from owner to read/use.